# How to properly update props in redux store?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a React App with a shopping cart component. I use Redux to update the shopping cart when clicking on a "Add to cart" button in an item. **The problem is, even I update the props in the item component, the prop is not updating concurrently.** When I'm checking the props in the component in the Chrom developer tools components tab, I can see the props are updating only when I navigate to another component. **However, the cart component never receives the updated prop to populate the cart items.** These are the necessary components.

**Items component**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ProductData from './DataSet/ProductData';
import { compose } from 'recompose';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { updateCartList } from '../../store/actions';

class LatestProducts extends Component {

    addItemToCart = (id) => {
        const { cartList, updateCartList } = this.props;
        var items = cartList;
        ProductData.forEach(each => {
            if (each.id === id) {
                items.push(each)
            }
        });
        updateCartList(items);
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <div>
                <div className="itemGridMain">
                    {
                        ProductData.map(product => {
                            return (
                                <div className="itemCard" key={product.id}>
                                    <button onClick={() => this.addItemToCart(product.id)}>Add to cart</button>
                                </div>
                            )
                        })
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        cartList: state.cartList,
    };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return bindActionCreators({
        updateCartList: updateCartList,
    }, dispatch);
}

export default compose(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps))(LatestProducts);
```

**Cart component**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { compose } from 'recompose';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { updateCartList } from '../../store/actions';

class FrontHeader extends Component {

    render() {

        const { cartList } = this.props;

        return (
            <div className="cartList">
                {
                    cartList && cartList.length > 0 && cartList.map(item => {
                        return (
                            <div className="listItem" key={item.id}>
                            </div>
                        )
                    })
                }
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        cartList: state.cartList,
    };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return bindActionCreators({
        updateCartList: updateCartList,
    }, dispatch);
}

export default compose(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps))(FrontHeader);
```

**Cart List Reducer**

```
const cartListReducer = (state = [], action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'UPDATE_CARTLIST':
            return action.payload;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export default cartListReducer;
```

**Cart List Index**

```
import cartListReducer from './cartlist';
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

const allReducers = combineReducers({
    cartList: cartListReducer,
})

export default allReducers;
```

**Redux Actions**

```
export const updateCartList = (newCartList) => {
    return {
        type: 'UPDATE_CARTLIST',
        payload: newCartList,
    }
}
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Issue

`this.props.cartList` is your state and by pushing into that array and saving it back into state you are simply mutating state.

```
addItemToCart = (id) => {
    const { cartList, updateCartList } = this.props;
    var items = cartList; // <-- state reference
    ProductData.forEach(each => {
        if (each.id === id) {
            items.push(each) // <-- push into state reference
        }
    });
    updateCartList(items); // <-- saved state reference
}
```

## Solution

You should provide a new array object reference for react to pick up the difference since reconciliation uses shallow object equality.

Your `addItemToCart` should probably just take the item you want added to the cart and move the cart update logic to the reducer.

LatestProducts

```
class LatestProducts extends Component {

  addItemToCart = (item) => {
    const { updateCartList } = this.props;
    updateCartList(item); // <-- pass item to action creator
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="itemGridMain">
          {ProductData.map(product => {
            return (
              <div className="itemCard" key={product.id}>
                <button
                  onClick={() => this.addItemToCart(product)} // <-- pass product/item
                >
                  Add to cart
                </button>
              </div>)
            })
          }
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

cartListReducer

```
const cartListReducer = (state = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'UPDATE_CARTLIST':
      return [...state, action.payload]; // <-- copy state and appen new item

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked!. Never noticed that the reducer should return a new array object reference

Comment: @DavidJohns Remember, react components rerender when state (i.e. component state) or props change (i.e. redux state provided via props). If the prop object reference doesn't change then react assumes the value didn't change.